# Error in compiling python3 with kivy to use toolchain command to create xcode project

Tags: python, xcode, compilation, kivy, toolchain

I have been stuck on this command for some time and i don't know how to fix the error. I am running the following command line to create an xcode project from my kivy code:

```
toolchain create myproject /Users/paria/PycharmProjects/pythonProject
```

I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR   ] No python recipe compiled!
[ERROR   ] You must have compiled at least python3
[ERROR   ] recipe to be able to create a project.
```

I have ran all the previous codes necessary and I think I have compiled python since I ran the following code: `toolchain build python3 kivy` but it still doesn't seem to be compiled.
Can anyone please assist me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! in order to receive helpful feedback please include more context, such as code snippets, what you are trying to achieve, etc.

Comment: I have this problem as well, would like to see an answer soon.